# Adding images to my Powerpoint Theme

Tags: themes, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I've been reading about making themes for PowerPoints but, the problem is, none of them get in very much detail.  Not even the Microsoft one.  I have two images per slide.  A top bar with out logo and a bottom one for looks.  Problem is, when I save the theme and then apply it to something else, the font colors, etc. change, but the images aren't added.

Can somebody help me to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you need to do is add your image to the slide master or one or more of the custom layouts before saving as theme.

Comment: Adding it to the slide master worked great.  Thanks a ton :D